# python sparse matrix get maximum values and index

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, csr

I have a sparse matrix A(equal to 10 * 3 in dense), such as:

```
print type(A)
<class scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix>

print A
(0, 0)  0.0160478743808
(0, 2)  0.0317314165078
(1, 2)  0.0156596521648
(1, 0)  0.0575683686558
(2, 2)  0.0107481166871
(3, 0)  0.0150580924929
(3, 2)  0.0297743235876
(4, 0)  0.0161931803955
(4, 2)  0.0320187296788
(5, 2)  0.0106034409766
(5, 0)  0.0128109177074
(6, 2)  0.0105766993238
(6, 0)  0.0127786088452
(7, 2)  0.00926522256063
(7, 0)  0.0111941023699
```

The max values for each column is:

```
print A.max(axis=0)
(0, 0)  0.0575683686558
(0, 2)  0.0320187296788
```

I would like to get the **index corresponding to the column value**.
I know that the

```
A.getcol(i).tolist()
```

will return me a list of each column which allow me to use argmax() function, but this way is really slow. I am wondering is there any descent way to do?

Comment: Is your matrix able to fit in memory? Doing `A.todense().argmax(axis=0)` would do what you want as long as the `A.todense()` is possible.

Comment: `argmax` would be a nice enhancement to the scipy sparse matrices.  In the meantime: Can you switch to CSC format?  If so, there is a way to get the argmax of the columns fairly efficiently.

Comment: @kbrose, the .todense() not possible since the size of data doesn't fit the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slight variation of the method you suggested in the question:

```
col_argmax = [A.getcol(i).A.argmax() for i in range(A.shape[1])]
```

(The `.A` attribute is equivalent to `.toarray()`.)

A potentially more efficient alternative is

```
B = A.tocsc()
col_argmax = [B.indices[B.indptr[i] + B.data[B.indptr[i]:B.indptr[i+1]].argmax()] for i in range(len(B.indptr)-1)]
```

---

Either of the above will work, but I have to ask: if your array has shape (10, 3), why are you using a sparse matrix?  (10, 3) is small! Just use a regular, dense numpy array.

Even if you keep `A` as a sparse matrix, the most efficient way to compute the argmax of the columns of a matrix that size is probably to just convert it to a dense array and use the argmax method:

```
col_argmax = A.A.argmax(axis=0)
```

Comment: Hi Warren, a lot of thanks for your answer! I test your solution and it faster then A.toarray() or .todense() function.

Comment: The only problem is, your method doesn't work when one or sparse matrix column is empty( full by 0.). In this case  just return a random number for me is fine,  so i change a lite bit of your code to:
    
    def get_max(i):
        try:
            index = B.data[B.indptr[i]:B.indptr[i+1]].argmax()
        except:
            # the sum of column is zero
            # in other word, this test doc not has any word appear in train doc
            index = -1
        return index
    maxval_index = [B.indices[B.indptr[i] + get_max(i)] for i in range(len(B.indptr)-1)]

Comment: For you question why I choose sparse matrix, since my really size of A matrix is 100k * 300k and I would like to calculate the inner product of A with another large matrix. The CSR.dot function is pretty fast. This is the reason I choose sparse matrix.

Comment: *"...since my really size of A matrix is 100k * 300k..."*  OK, that's a good reason for using a sparse matrix.  You should include that information in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The more efficient way to get the max and argmax values in each matrix column is simply using **scipy.sparse native** functions:

- **max value** of A in each matrix columns:

  `max_values = A.max(axis=0)`
- **max arg** of A in each matrix column:

  `max_args = A.argmax(axis=0)`

The same to compute max values and arg max in each matrix row (using *axis=1*) or to compute max values and arg max of all the matrix (using *axis=None*).